# How to differentiate without knowing the function, only the inputs?

Tags: functions, economics

Given a function $f(p, \alpha w)$, where $\alpha > 0$, how do I differentiate with respect to $\alpha$ ? The answer is supposedly $ w D_w f(p,w) $ (it says that it differentiated with respect to $\alpha$ and evaluated at $\alpha =1$). I don't fully understand why this is the case.

Comment: You might ignore the first coordinate. Then this becomes a chain rule in single variable calculus, which you might fund easier top grok.

Comment: I think it is differentiated with respect to $\color{red}w$. By using the chain rule it becomes $w\cdot f_w(p,\alpha w)$. In your notation it is $w\cdot D_wf(p,\alpha w)$. Now you set $\alpha$ equal to 1. This results in $w\cdot D_wf(p,w)$.